# Layout_align not working

Tags: android, android-layout, android-styles

I am new to android studio and had earlier used `layout_alignParentBottom="true"` and other alignment commands which worked well. 
I was even getting the recommendation comments that android studio gives if it recognises a command.

But Now I created a new project and Android_studio here the code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  tools:context="com.example.shaurya.courtcounter.MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="368dp"
    android:layout_height="495dp"
    android:background="#ffdab9"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Team A"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/team_a_score"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="0"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/threepoints"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="increment_three"
        android:text="3 Points" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/twopoints"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="increment_two"
        android:text="2 Points" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/onepoints"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="increment_one"
        android:text="Free Throw" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

        android:text="reset" />


</LinearLayout>
```

``

**At the extreme end of the cde there is a button which I a trying to align but alignment is not working**

[image: Layout ScreenShot]

Comment: one more thing if anyone can help 
In the code I am giving LinearLayout height and weight as match_parent but automaticcaly it gives that tag some fixed value. Why I am not able to give match_parent to linearlayout

Answer (score 1):

align attributes you used:

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
```

dosen't belong to linear layout behaviors, it's belonging to RelativeLayout.

so if you need to reach center for reset button with linearLayout, use

`android:layout_gravity="center|anygravityYouWant"`
and  `android:gravity="center"`.

also you facing some issue with width and height for linearLayout, because you are using ConstraintLayout as parent Layout.

Comment: for the linearlayout height and weight can u plz have a look at that

Comment: So whats the solution for the constraint layout thing what should I add so that I get a full screen background and textviews

Comment: @shauryauppal  please view [more about constraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html) if you not familiar with it yet.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the Relative Layout as your Parent Layout-

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ffdab9">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Team A"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/team_a_score"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="0"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/threepoints"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="increment_three"
        android:text="3 Points" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/twopoints"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="increment_two"
        android:text="2 Points" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/onepoints"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="increment_one"
        android:text="Free Throw" />
</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:text="reset" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  tools:context="com.example.shaurya.courtcounter.MainActivity">    CAN YOU EXPLAIN THIS DEFAULT LINE WHY IS IT CONSTRAINT LAYOUT

Comment: ConstraintLayout should work if constraints are applied correctly

Comment: By default, the new XML layout file is defined with ConstraintLayout as the parent layout. Replace `<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>` with `<RelativeLayout>`

Comment: @shauryauppal ConstraintLayout is the default. Since Android Studio 2.3... Feel free to replace entirely with whatever layout you want.